# How to insert code cell variable into a markdown cell latex code?

Tags: python, latex, markdown, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Is it possible to create a variable in a code cell on Jupyter (running Python) and call this variable in a markdown cell? I want to put the variable into a LaTex expression.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! If my answer worked for you please consider marking it as accepted and upvoting it. If you are still having trouble please add comments to that answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could format the output of a function with [IPython.display.Markdown](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.Markdown).